# Find a solution of optimal problem with an inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, optimal-control

Let $a,b,x$ be vectors in $R^n$, A be a matrix, $c,d \in R, c<d$. Solve the following problem:
$$\begin{cases}
\text{minimize} \quad (b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)\\
(a^Tx-c).(a^Tx-d) \leq 0
\end{cases}$$
Assume that $A,a,b$ are good enough for my problem. How can I solve it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, just thought of sharing my thought. Why dont you try using  using Matlab? Such as Fmincon? To start with you may have to write

```
function f=objecfun(x)
```

$ f=b^{\rm T}b-b^{\rm T}Ax-x^{\rm T}A^{\rm T}b+x^{\rm T}A^{\rm T}Ax$

```
function [c,c_eq]=nonlconstr(x)
```

$ c=[(a^{\rm T}x)^2-a^{\rm T}xd-ca^{\rm T}x+cd];$%nonlinear inequality constraint

```
c_eq=[];% as you have no equality constraint
```

And use fmincon solver; get more details from Matlab command window by using Help fmincon, or follow [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-tool-with-the-fmincon-solver.html) link.

I suggest this as your objective function and constriants are nonlinear in $x$. And hence deriving an analytical solution using lagrange approach may be quite involving. fmincon utilzes numerical methods to solve the problem.

Hope this helps